Attempting to write to disk and check the before and after availability of space using statvfs, but I see no change in blocks available
I am using statvfs to monitor my disk space. I run this program and see no changes in the amount of available blocks within my system, but when I run the df command I am able to see that there's disk memory being used.
What am I doing wrong?
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   struct statvfs buff;
   const char* path = "/dev/mapper/rhel-home";

   if (statvfs(path, &buff) != 0)
   {
      std::cout << "error\n";
   }

   std::cout << "buff.f_blocks: " << buff.f_blocks<< "\n";
   std::cout << "buff.f_bfree: "  << buff.f_bfree << "\n";
   
   const size_t GB = (1024 * 1024) * 1024;

   std::vector<char> data(GB, 'A');
   
   std::ofstream file("output.data", std::ios::binary);
   if (!file)
   {
      std::cout << "file error\n";
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      file.write(data.data(), GB);
      file.flush();

      std::cout  << "Wrote 1 GB to disk, iteration " << i + 1 << "\n";

   }

   file.close();
   std::cout << "Completed writing to disk\n";

   if (statvfs(path, &buf) != 0)
   {
      std::cout << "error\n";
   }
  
   std::cout << "buff.f_blocks: " << buf.f_blocks<< "\n";
   std::cout << "buff.f_bfree: "  << buff.f_bfree << "\n";
   
   return 0;

}```


Is the file output.data actually appearing somewhere inside /dev/mapper/rhel-home?  (Since you don't specify a path for it, it will be written to your program's current directory, which could be somewhere else).  Also, note that after the first time you run this program, it will overwrite the existing output.data file rather than create a new file, so the total disk space used won't change.

I was under the impression that /dev/mapper/rhel-home was a file system in linux that encompassed all of the disk space on my VM. This made me think that if I did any type of writing to disk anywhere within my system, that it'd be reflected in my statvfs calls. I changed the path to a directory where my output.data file was being created and written to and now I am able to view the changes in available blocks. Thank you so much.
